# How do I change -webkit-color-swatch properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I had to make a costum color picker for work. i used `-webkit-color-swatch` to change how the color picker looked and I also used it to add a background image over it.

Whenever I click on the ColorPicker the background image should disappear, so you just see your standard color picker. this however does not work.

This is the code I used

JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById("short-text-yk693v5pm").onclick = function() {
    removeColorGradient()
};

function removeColorGradient() {
    document.getElementById("short-text-yk693v5pm").style['-webkit-color-swatch'] = "none";
}
document.getElementById("short-text-yk693v5pm").value = "#FFFFFF";
```

CSS

```css
#short-text-yk693v5pm::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/color-gradient.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Have a look through your browsers devtools inspect facility console to see if there are errors. You cant select the way you are trying to on a pseudo element in JS.

Comment: there's no errors, i changed the code from document.getElementById() to document get.querySelector() but it still doesn't work sadly

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? I can't repeat your code (background etc changing) and the error I see isn't explicit, it is the **absence** of any styling of the input element when I look at the CSS attached to it in the inspection. Does you browser have an extension which recognises -webkit-color-swatch as it is non-standard.